# iOS How to play multiple videos on one view

Tags: ios, ios6

I was wondering how to play multiple videos in one page, like where you have two buttons, and when you press one, it plays a video, and when you press the other it plays a different one. I have this code so far:

```
-(void)WelcomeVideo1
{
    NSURL *url31 = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle]
                                         pathForResource:@"DirectorsWelcome" ofType:@"mp4"]];
    welcomePlayer1 =  [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc]
                      initWithContentURL:url31];

    welcomePlayer1.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleDefault;
   welcomePlayer1.shouldAutoplay = YES;
    [self.view addSubview:welcomePlayer1.view];
    [welcomePlayer1 setFullscreen:YES animated:YES];
}

-(void) moviePlayBackDidFinish:(NSNotification *)aNotification{
    [welcomePlayer1.view removeFromSuperview];
    welcomePlayer1 = nil;
}

- (void)moviePlayerWillExitFullscreen:(NSNotification*) aNotification {
      [welcomePlayer1 stop];
    [welcomePlayer1.view removeFromSuperview];
   welcomePlayer1 = nil;
}


-(void)storyVideo1
{
    NSURL *url4 = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle]
                                          pathForResource:@"OurStory" ofType:@"mp4"]];
    storyPlayer1 =  [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc]
                       initWithContentURL:url4];

    storyPlayer1.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleDefault;
    storyPlayer1.shouldAutoplay = YES;
    [self.view addSubview:storyPlayer1.view];
    [storyPlayer1 setFullscreen:YES animated:YES];
}

-(void) moviePlayBackDidFinish2:(NSNotification *)aNotification{
    [storyPlayer1.view removeFromSuperview];
    storyPlayer1 = nil;
}

- (void)moviePlayerWillExitFullscreen2:(NSNotification*) aNotification {
    [storyPlayer1 stop];
    [storyPlayer1.view removeFromSuperview];
    storyPlayer1 = nil;
}
```

but whenever I try to play both videos, the 2nd one I play crashes the app. Any ideas?

Comment: Did it crash immediately when you start the 2nd movie or after it is played?

Comment: Immediately when you start the 2nd one

Answer (score 0):

Use [`AVPlayer`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVPlayer_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and [`AVPlayerLayer`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVPlayer_Class/Reference/Reference.html) instead of `MPMoviePlayerController`.
Take a look into following [apple example](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/samplecode/AVPlayerDemo/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010101).